# About the meaning of an equation on the book 'Classical field theory' of Landau & Lifshitz

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, speed

In the chapter 'Constant gravitational field' of the book 'Classical field theory' of the authors, there is the following equation:
$$v=\dfrac{dl}{d\tau}=\dfrac{c}{\sqrt{ g_{00}}}\dfrac{dl}{dx^0}$$
Now, the term $$\dfrac{dl}{d\tau}$$ is itself a speed.
What is the difference between $v$ and $\dfrac{dl}{dx^0}?$

Comment: I'd suggest explicitly writing out what the parameters mean, and why you think $\frac{\text{d}l}{\text{d}\tau}$ is a "velocity". (Also, whose velocity, and with respect to whom?)

Comment: @Riccardo.Alestra The velocity of a given curve $x^\mu(\lambda)$ on a spacetime manifold is defined as $v = \frac{dx^\mu}{d\lambda}$. If the curve is the one of a massive particle you can parametrise it with the proper time $\tau$, $dx^0\equiv dt$ is the coordinate time and derivation by it won't give you the tangent vector to the curve.